# Proof of radius of a circle based on an equilateral triangle and a square.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

I need help proving this:

ABC is an equilateral triangle; $BCDE$ is a square. Both figures have sides of length $2cm$. Pentagon $ACDEB$ lies inside a circle that passes through points $A, D$ and $E$. We want to know the radius of the circle.

[image: Drawing of problem]

Answer (score 3):

$\angle ABE = 60\,^{\circ} + 90\,^{\circ} = 150 \,^{\circ}$. Since, $ABE$ is isosceles, $\angle AEB = \frac{180\,^{\circ} -150\,^{\circ}}{2} = 15 \,^{\circ}$. So, $\angle AED = 90\,^{\circ}- 15\,^{\circ} = 75\,^{\circ}$. Since, $AED$ is isosceles, $\angle EAD = 180\,^{\circ} -(75\,^{\circ} + 75\,^{\circ}) = 30\,^{\circ}$.

So, circumradius of $ADE$:
$$R = \frac{ED}{2\cdot \sin EAD } = \frac{2}{2\cdot\sin 30} = 2 \text{cm}$$

Answer (score 2):

Call $\;O\;$ the circle's center and $\;M\;$ the intersection of $\;ED\;$ with $\;AO\;$. Check and prove the following:

$$\Delta ABE\;,\;\;\Delta AOE\;\;\text{are isosceles triangles, and thus}$$

$$\angle BAE=\angle BEA\;,\;\;\angle OAE=\angle OEA$$

and since $\;\angle BAO=30^\circ\;$ , we get that $\;\angle MEO=60^\circ\;$ , and from here that $\;\Delta MEO\;$ is a 
 $\;30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ\;$ right triangle, and thus

$$1=EM=\frac12EO$$